# how to authenticate my facebook page?

Tags: facebook

i registered my app and i got client_id,secret_id,etc.. (http://developers.facebook.com/setup/)

i had already authenticate my app in my facebook account

i created new page in facebook ( http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php )

how to authenticate my app on the page which I had created?

thx..

Comment: Do you mean you want your app to act on behalf of your page (post on the page wall from app as page admin)?

Comment: absolutely yes..

how to do that?

i must get new access token?

how to authorize my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this process is described in details: [Posting To Facebook Fan Page Wall As Admin](http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/)

Answer (score -2):

If you went to your app settings you could have created a page already connected to your app, otherwise they will always remain seperate.

See screenshot

[image: screenshot]